# WCF services, SSL, message security and digital certificates

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, https

I am trying to set up a WCF web service with message security as well as SSL. Message security uses a username and password to authenticate the client to the server and an X501 digital certificate on the server to authenticate the server to the client. Is an X501 certificate and an SSL certificate the same thing? Can I use the same certificate for both?

If the X501 certificate is independent of SSL, how do I go about getting one? Do you have to pay for them? Are they issued by the same companies that issue SSL certificates? And is this something that is commonly supported by web hosting companies?

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a GeoTrust SSL certificate for my domain and with this one certificate, I was successfully able to get all of Transport security, Message security and TransportWithMessageCredential security to work.

With Message and TransportWithMessageCredential security, I am using MessageCredentialType = UserName.